# Fragment View's state is broken by FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I wanted to retain views through fragment replace operation and noticed a strange bug:

After fragment's View is destroyed through replace operation, it still has a parent, however, the parent doesn't have the view among its children.

```
private View view;

@Override 
public View onCreateView(...) {
  if (view == null) {
      view = // ... inflate view
  } else {
      // at this point, view has mParent, but can't be removed
      // because the parent does not have it among its children
  }
  return view;
}

@Override 
public void onDestroyView() {
    // I could remove the view from its parent here manually, 
    // however, it will cause fragment's content to disappear before
    // the replace animation ends
}
```

[image: debugger screenshot]

Notice how the view has a reference to its parent through `mParent`, but the parent has zero `mChildrenCount`.

This causes fragment transaction to crash with an exception when trying to reuse the view:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`. I find this behavior to be exceptionally wrong since it leaves the fragment's view in an unusable state.

If someone has faced this issue, please share your workarounds. I have come up with a temporary dirty reflective solution:

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(...) {
  if (view == null) {
      view = // ... inflate view
  } else {
      // clear parent reference (because SDK fails to do it)
      Field f = View.class.getDeclaredField("mParent");
      f.setAccessible(true);
      f.set(view, null);
  }
  return view;
}
```

Comment: how are you inflating your view in `onCreateView`? Are you using `inflate(int layoutRes, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`

Try experimenting with `attachToRoot` property